# How to use spring @ModelAttribute with builder patterns

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, builder-pattern

I am new to Builder Patterns and trying to figure out a way to use Builder patterns in my Spring models.

My previous model had all setter and getter methods which I replaced with Builder methods and the now the code looks something like this:

```
public class UserInterests {
    private final String user;
    private final int interestlevel;

    private UserInterests(UserInterestBuilder builder) {
        this.user = builder.user;
        this.interestlevel = builder.interestlevel;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public static class UserInterestBuilder {
        private String user;
        private int interestlevel;

        public UserInterestBuilder() {
        }

        public UserInterestBuilder user(final String userId) {
            this.user = user;
            return this;
        }

        public UserInterestBuilder interestLevel(final int interestLevel) {
            this.interestLevel = interestLevel;
            return this;
        }

        public UserInterests build() {
            return new UserInterests(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Previously, without builders I was taking the user interestlevel from the UI (jsp) and was binding it to a UserInterests model. In the controller I was using @ModelAttribute to get the instance of the UserInterests and was using it.

Controller snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addInterest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addUserInterest(
        @ModelAttribute(USER_INTEREST) UserInterests userInterests,
        BindingResult result, HttpSession session, ModelAndView model) {
//do something here
}
```

JSP snippet

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form:form modelAttribute="userInterests" action="addInterest" 
method="post">
<!-- Do more -->
</body>
</html>
```

But, since I changed the model to use builders, I cannot use userInterests model instance as the constructor of this is private. I can get the user and interestlevel values separately using request.getParameter() and bind to userInterests model using build. But is there a way to use @ModelAttribute for builders directly with having to get values separately.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ModelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) annotation is handled by `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` and attributes are populated via data binding to Servlet request parameters.
Witthin the guts of DataBinder is following method which actually does the binding

```
protected void applyPropertyValues(MutablePropertyValues mpvs) {
        try {
            // Bind request parameters onto target object.
            getPropertyAccessor().setPropertyValues(mpvs, isIgnoreUnknownFields(), isIgnoreInvalidFields());
        }
        catch (PropertyBatchUpdateException ex) {
            // Use bind error processor to create FieldErrors.
            for (PropertyAccessException pae : ex.getPropertyAccessExceptions()) {
                getBindingErrorProcessor().processPropertyAccessException(pae, getInternalBindingResult());
            }
        }
    }
```

Looking at [`BeanWrapperImpl`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.html) which is the most common property accessor, it has a basic feature of Auto-registering default [`property editors`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/package-summary.html) from the spring packages in addition to the JDK's standard PropertyEditors, so basically it's completely linked to [`JavaBeans`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) ( basically properties and their accessors with special naming convention) which means it has no support for any other style like in your case Builder pattern.

Comment: So, is there a way to use builder patterns with my dependency injection.

Comment: If you want automatic data binding facility then no you cannot. You will have to convert the modelAtrribute manually to other object using the builder API.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use your builder to inject UserInterests, you can write your own [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) that will inspect the request and use the UserInterestBuilder to provide the instance of UserInterests. In particular, I find it a bit forced and this scenario could be made more simple by creating objects by using Command or Form objects to bind parameters to.